# How to implement free plans in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

To implement a free plan for a subscription, I have created a plan with a monthly charge of $0.

1. Is this the correct way to subscribe users to a free plan so that they don't have to pay?
2. Will users still get invoices when they are subscribed to a free plan? If so, how can I avoid sending invoices to those subscribed to the free plan?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in Stripe at all? Just... don't have a subscription at all for those users.

Answer (score 8):

Stripe Subscriptions are designed to manage billing and payments, rather than "tracking who is using a product". An "active" Subscription in Stripe is one that is being paid for, rather than one that is "being actively used".

You could conceivably set up a Subscription with an indefinite [free trial](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials), but really, you're doing a bunch of work to keep updating it to "remain free". I'd suggest taking a look at what you are actually trying to accomplish, because you're probably trying to track a user of your services, rather than track that a user doesn't pay you anything.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to track a subscription with a zero plan on Stripe it will of course work. I use zero plans all the time.

All the invoices will be generated each month but will have a zero value which means they will automatically be marked as paid.

`Invoice was finalized and automatically marked as paid because the amount due was 0.00kr`

I am using custom accounts with custom integration so there is no automatic email going out from stripe for me, but I do receive the entire stack of events like I would any normal invoice which i have to deal with.

The event progression is: `Invoice created -> finalized -> paid -> changed`. Although instant the webhook events all come in.

There is no issue with zero plans, everything shows up in the Stripe admin and works just like any subscription. You can start out with a free plan and upgrade them later - the payment information is gathered and can be charged later so it is all good.